# Pnpm cannot find modules after project renaming

Tags: pnpm

After renaming project folder pnpm throws error "Cannot find module...".

At first times pnpm gives me a message for changing "virtual-store-dir", but I'm not receiving them any more, just getting an error.

So, how safety to rename project folder?

Comment: Actually all the symlinks get broken when you rename a folder. Rerun `pnpm i` in your project, everything should work fine.

Comment: Thank, problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `pnpm i` after renaming, this will recreate node-modules for the new directory name